# C++ getline takes nothing

Tags: c++

I have got this C++ code

```
cin>>a>>b;
getline(cin,str2);
```

Where `a - Int`,`b - double` and `str2 - string`.So when my input should be

`12
 4.0
 best coding website`

My program only takes 12 and 4 and then exits the program taking `str2` as an empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's still a new line in the stream. `getline` will fall for it and return `""`. Just use:

```
cin.ignore();
```

That will ignore the persisting newline and move on to the data you want.

Comment: Thanks it worked!